# couchdb revs_limit in one way continuous replication

Tags: couchdb

I understand that replication back and forth between two databases can introduce conflicts, but if its one way (master-slave) is that really possible?

If conflicts aren't a concern in this scenario, I would like to decrease the revs_limit from the default of 1000 to 100

Comment: If conflicts are never a concern, you can reduce it to 0.

Comment: So I am correct in assuming conflicts can only be introduced with bidirection replication?

Comment: No. Conflicts can be introduced with uni-directional replication, too.  Conflicts can happen any time you update docs in more than one place. If your slaves are read-only, then uni-directional sync will not allow conflicts, though.

Comment: Ahh, so since I'm treating them as master-slave that won't be a problem. I would just have to turn the revs_limit back to 1k if I wanted to use a cluster? Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: You need to set revs_limit to a value sufficiently high that you're able to find a common history when doing a sync. If you do constant syncing, and few updates, revs_limit=10, or maybe even 2, would be enough to resolve all conflicts.  1000 is just a conservatively high default, practically guaranteed to work in all but the most extreme situations.